# I cannot use SVN on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, svn, osx-snow-leopard

I created svn server on my MacOS Snow Leopard following [these steps](https://gigaom.com/2010/02/10/how-to-setup-a-svn-server-under-os-x-10-6/). But It's working only on MacOS. I don't know why.

My Windows is 192.168.0.100, MacOS is 192.168.0.101. I'm sure, because I test it by `ipconfig getpacket en1` and `ipconfig /all`. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check Windows Firewall?  Look here: http://thinkdiff.net/mixed/running-subversion-on-windows-7/

Comment: Yeah, I did. I can to connect other SVN in my Windows 7. But I cannot to connect to my MacOS.

Comment: Out of svn, can your Windows ping your Mac ? Try this in your Windows command line: `ping 192.168.0.101`

Comment: Yes! I can do it. And I got packets.

Comment: I guess the username in the URL can make problems. Try the checkout without it. SVN should prompt for credentials when it needs them. Also try the command line client. Maybe you get a better error message. "svn checkout --username ivan svn://192.168.0.101" Does it need a specific port?